# Update a child row

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a problem with a foreign key attribute in my data base Cannot add or update a child row i think the problem is here in the code bellow :

```
    @RequestMapping( value = "/saveeeee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView doSave(@RequestParam("user_id") String user_id, @RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("password") String password,@RequestParam("rol") String rol){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/utilisateurs");
    User op;
    op = new User();

    Role ro;
    ro = new Role();

    ro.setRole(rol);

    if(!user_id.isEmpty()){
        op =(User)appRepo.findOne(Integer.parseInt(user_id));
    } else {
        op = new User();
    }

    op.setUsername(username);
    op.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
    ro.setUser(op);
    ro.setUsername(op.getUsername());

    op.setRo(ro);



    appRepo.save(op);
    return mv;
}
```

The entities :

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

public Role ro;
public int user_id;
public String username;
public String password;
public int enabled = 1;

public User() {
}



public User(String username, String password, int enabled) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.enabled = enabled;

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Role getRo() {
    return ro;
}

public void setRo(Role ro) {
    this.ro = ro;
}









@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "enabled")
public int getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}





}
```

_

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {

public int user_role_id;
public String username;
public String role;
public User user;

public void setUser_role_id(int user_role_id) {
    this.user_role_id = user_role_id;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "ro")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}



public Role(String username, String role) {
    this.username = username;
    this.role = role;
}

public Role() {
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getUser_role_id() {
    return user_role_id;
}


@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "role")
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

}

My sql shema :

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`enabled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
`user_role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`role` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uni_username_role` (`role`,`username`),
KEY `fk_username_idx` (`username`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` 
(`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My error is :

om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`user_roles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`))